# Lightswitch RIA Service replay attack

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Are RIA Services created by Lightswitch secured against replay attack?

If not, is here some solution for do this?

Or, is it possible configure endpoint of generated WCF RIA service?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Silverlight need binary endpoint of RIA Service only. This endpoint uses CustomBinding with  HttpTransportBindingElement and BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.
More informations [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx).
I try find some solution how to get this binding programatically and add securityElement to it.

In my opinion, I can not secure Silverlight 's RIA Service against replay attack. Why? Because of security cheklist from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) - there is no mention about this attack.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I found solution for WCF services - [here](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Replay%20detection%20to%20protect%20against%20message%20replay%20attacks). But, I don't know how to configure endpoints of RIA services generated by LS for applying <security> element.